# Youtube api getDuration method returns the same timing

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I wrote this script using Youtube api. It slides an overlay box over the video at specified time durations.

Everything works smoothly except the player.getDuration():Number method. It keeps returning the same timing and doesn't move ahead as the video progresses.

Below is the relevant piece of code. The complete code is available here https://github.com/BennyThadikaran/videoOverlay

init method stores the youtube Player obj in the player variable and uses setInterval to run activateOverlay every second.

activateOverlay gets the current run time of the video and check if its time to activate the overlay.

```
var vidPlugin = (function() {
  var data,
      player,

      activateOverlay = function() {
        // get the current time
        var t = player.getDuration(),
            keys = Object.keys(data);

        for (key in data) {
          if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (t >= data[key].start && t <= data[key].end) {
              showOverlay(key);
            }
          }
        }
        if (t >= data[key].end) {
          hideOverlay();
        }
      },

      init = function(youtubeObj, dataObj) {
        data = dataObj;
        player = youtubeObj;

        var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");

        generateOverlay();

        wrapper.addEventListener("click", runModal);
      },

      handler = function(e) {
        if (e.data === 1) {
          // if playing run activateOverlay function every second
          int = setInterval(function() {
            activateOverlay();
          }, 1000);
          wrapper.className = "wrapper wrapper-hide";
        }

        if (e.data === 2) {
          // paused
          clearInterval(int);
          wrapper.className = "wrapper wrapper-show scale-up-hor-right";
        }
      };

      return {
        init: init,
        handler: handler
      }
}());

window.onload = function() {
  vidPlugin.init(player, {
    0:{
      Name: "Item 1",
      Image: "https://via.placeholder.com/45",
      Description: "ipsom Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
      start: 1,
      end: 5
    },
    1:{
      Name: "Item 2",
      Image: "https://via.placeholder.com/45",
      Description: "ipsom Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
      start: 7,
      end: 11
    }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong method

player.getCurrentTime():Number provides the time elapsed in seconds.